# ERROR TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'setItem')

Tags: javascript, angular

```
private currentStorage = null;

setItem(key: string, value: string) {
    this.currentStorage.setItem(key, value);
}
```

When I run my code (the above snippet is the only one that contains the setItem) I get the following error:

```
ERROR TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'setItem')
    at SessionService.setItem (session.service.ts:53:23)
    at authentication.service.ts:58:37
    at map.js:7:1
    at OperatorSubscriber._next (OperatorSubscriber.js:13:1)
    at OperatorSubscriber.next (Subscriber.js:31:1)
    at map.js:7:1
    at OperatorSubscriber._next (OperatorSubscriber.js:13:1)
    at OperatorSubscriber.next (Subscriber.js:31:1)
    at filter.js:6:50
    at OperatorSubscriber._next (OperatorSubscriber.js:13:1)
```

I've tried many ways to define the `currentStorage` but the error is the same or sometimes says "properties of undefined" instead of "properties of null".

Can anyone explain what is happening?

Comment: You could try `this.currentStorage?.setItem(key, value);` but that's kinda turning a blind eye to the problem that you're trying to change the storage of something that doesn't seem to exist. Is there more code you can provide?

Comment: There are [thousands of questions about the error in the title](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=Cannot+read+properties+of+null). All of them point to the fact that you have something null that you are attempting to access a property of (in this case, `this.currentStorage`). You'll need to set that to something other than null (like `localStorage` or `sessionStorage`).

Answer (score -1):

this was all could provide based on question

```
setItem(key: string, value: string) {
        if(this.currentStorage){
        this.currentStorage.setItem(key, value);
        }
        else{
         ...
         //could do nothing here or create the storage
         this.currentStorage = ...
         this.currentStorage.setItem(key, value);
        }
    }
```

but if you are looking for actual change needed for session storage

```
    setItem(key: string, value: string) : void {
            sessionStorage.setItem(key, JSON.stringify(value));
        }
    
    /** get an item from session storage */
    getItem(string: key) : any | undefined{
 let value = sessionStorage.getItem(key);
if(value){
return JSON.parse(value);
}
return undefined;
}
```

Comment: This works for me, but I can see that is just a temporary workaround. Nevertheless, thanks!

Comment: well you do not provide any detail on your application structure so is all can provide